# Modeling uncertainty from known physics

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, time-series, machine-learning-model, rnn

I have an equation given by:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} t}=4a−2s+\lambda(s)
$$

where, $a$ is an input constant and $\lambda$ is a non-linear term that depends on $s$.

I know that the true solution for $\lambda\left(s\right)$ is $\sin \left( s\right) \cos\left(s\right)$

I have generated data from [0, 5]s with the true solution and with the equation excluding the non-linear term for a range of initial conditions and a range of $a$'s.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def foo_true(t, s, a):
    ds_dt = 4*a -2*s + np.sin(s)*np.cos(s)
    return ds_dt

def foo(t, s, a):
    ds_dt = 4*a -2*s
    return ds_dt


# Settings:
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000) 

a_s = np.arange(1, 10)
s0_s = np.arange(1, 10)

# Store the data
df_true = pd.DataFrame({'time': t})
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': t})

# Generate the data
for a in a_s:
    for s0 in s0_s:
        sol_true = solve_ivp(foo_true, (t[0], t[-1]), (s0,), t_eval=t, args=(a,))
        df_true[f'{a}_{s0}'] = sol_true.y.T
        
for a in a_s:
    for s0 in s0_s:
        sol = solve_ivp(foo, (t[0], t[-1]), (s0,), t_eval=t, args=(a,))    
        df[f'{a}_{s0}'] = sol.y.T
```

In the above code, `df_true` is a data frame containing the actual dynamics of the system and `df` is the dynamics with a discrepancy.

The figure below shows an example of the discrepancy in the data:

[image]

Given that I know part of the physics, how can I model $\lambda$ with `pyTorch`?

Can I look into a paper/repo with a conceptually similar example?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I was searching for the same thing a while back and I came across the concept of **PINNs**.

Physics-informed neural networks (PINNs) are neural networks that encode model equations, such as partial differential equations (PDEs), as a component of the neural network itself.

[image]

[This article](https://www.dhuality.com/posts/2022-04-20-physical-neural-networks---the-harmonic-oscillator/) describes PINNs for a harmonic oscillator! [Code](https://github.com/benmoseley/harmonic-oscillator-pinn) for the harmonic oscillator problem.

[This link](https://towardsdatascience.com/physics-informed-neural-networks-pinns-an-intuitive-guide-fff138069563) describes the concept in detail with the help of a simple projectile motion example.

**Cheers!**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. This problem required to able to take in multiple solutions of the ODE and model the $\lambda$ term. Can `PINN`s take in multiple initial conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Modeling the non-linear term $λ(s)$ in your equation using PyTorch can be approached as a parameter estimation or function approximation problem. Since you know the true solution for $λ(s)$, you can use the generated data to train a neural network to approximate the non-linear term based on the given input and output values.

To model $λ(s)$ using PyTorch, you can treat it as a learnable parameter in a neural network and train the network to approximate the true $λ(s) = sin(s) * cos(s)$ based on the given data. Instead of using a single input $s$, you can use a concatenated input of $s$ and the corresponding solution values. This way, the model can learn the relationship between $λ(s)$ and the given solutions.

Here's an example of how you can implement this using PyTorch:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

# Define a custom dataset for the data
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx]

# Define a neural network to approximate λ(s)
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(2, 1)  # Input dimension is 2 (s and solution)

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.sin(x[:, 0]) * torch.cos(x[:, 0]) + self.linear(x)

# Prepare the data
data = df.values  # Include all columns
dataset = CustomDataset(data)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

# Create the model and optimizer
model = Model()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

# Training loop
num_epochs = 100
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch in dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        inputs = batch[:, :-1]  # Input data (exclude the last column)
        targets = batch[:, -1]  # True λ(s) values (last column)
        
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(), targets)
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {loss.item()}")

# Test the model
test_input = torch.tensor([[1.0, 0.0]])  # An example input (s=1.0, solution=0.0)
predicted_output = model(test_input)
print(f"Predicted λ(s) for input s=1.0: {predicted_output.item()}")


# Continue with your desired analysis or visualization using the predicted lambda values
```

This code defines a custom dataset class, a neural network model with a linear layer, sets up the optimizer and loss function, and trains the model using the provided data. The model approximates the true $λ(s)$ by combining the learned linear term with the sin(s)cos(s) term. The input dimension of the model is now 2, consisting of s and the corresponding solution value. The model's linear layer is adjusted accordingly to accommodate the concatenated input.

---

Regarding papers or repositories with similar examples, here are a few resources you can explore for inspiration:

1. [Physics-Informed Neural Networks: A Deep Learning Framework for Solving Forward and Inverse Problems Involving Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10561) by Raissi et al

   - This paper presents a physics-informed neural network approach for solving differential equations. It combines physical laws with data to train neural networks to approximate the unknown terms in the equations.
2. [Neural Ordinary Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07366) by Chen et al.

   - This paper introduces Neural Ordinary Differential Equations (NODEs), which use continuous-depth models to approximate the solution of differential equations. It provides insights into how neural networks can be used to represent differential equations.
3. [Physics-Informed Neural Networks (PINNs)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.05593): An Introduction and Recent Advances by Zhang et al.

   - This review paper introduces Physics-Informed Neural Networks (PINNs) and their applications in solving various physical problems. It discusses the integration of physics-based knowledge into neural networks.
   - You can explore the code and methodologies presented in these papers to gain a deeper understanding of modeling non-linear terms in physics using deep learning approaches.
4. DeepXDE: A Deep Learning Library for Solving Differential Equations by Lu, Weinan, and Zhongqiang Zhang.

   - GitHub repository: [deepxde](https://github.com/lululxvi/deepxde)
   - GitHub repository: [PINNs](https://github.com/maziarraissi/PINNs)

These references provide examples and implementations of neural network-based approaches for solving differential equations and may serve as a starting point for your work on modelling $λ(s)$ with PyTorch.

Remember that modelling $λ(s)$ using PyTorch is an iterative process that may require fine-tuning the network architecture, hyperparameters, and training procedure to achieve the best results for your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code produces an error. The shape of inputs is $[32, 81$ and the linear layers is expecting 2 entries

Comment: could you help me with the shape problem?